# "FORBIDDEN You don't have permission to access /greenfloyd/php/bm_edit_xml.php on this server."

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I've been sweating over this the last three days, I am baffled!

The input html launches an xml scan of a web site to gather text, images and links which populate a form for the user to select what they want to save.  (The output eventually becomes a bookmark stored at greenfloyd.org.)  The problem began a month or so ago, the scan started crashing with a "Forbidden 403" error pointing to my php code file, on the gf server (dir/file permission at 0644).  The problem revolves around the links (url and text) gathered and placed into a  box , the url is put in the value, and the link text into the innerHTML.  The default is that none of the links are selected, the user can then select one or more links from this box, or manually add a link via two  fields that get put into the select box, and become part of the form.

```
<form id = "bmInputForm" onsubmit = "bmSub(); return false;" onreset = "bmInputFormReset();" action = "http://greenfloyd.org/greenfloyd/php/bm_input_xml.php" method = "post" enctype = "multipart/form-data" class = "readerBox">...

<code><input type = "url" id = "link1Url" class = "input_size" size = "40" maxlength = "250" value ="" onclick = "this.select();" title = "Enter a standard url for this related link.">
<input id = "link1Title" class = "input_size" size = "40" maxlength = "150" value = "" onclick = "this.select();" title = "Enter a short title for this related link.">
<button type = "button" onclick = "relatedAdd()" title = "Add to related links list.">[+]</button>
<hr style="width:25%;">
<select id = "relatedSelect" name = "related_select[]" multiple title = "To select/unselect hold down the Ctrl key and click an option." onchange = "relatedCheck();" style = "width:80%;"></select></code>
```

The scan is an ajax xml call and returns elements from the target url, including the following:

```
<code>//echo "<related url='".rawurlencode($valid_url)."' txt='".htmlspecialchars($related_text, ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8')."'></related>";
    err = false;
    try { var relatedNode = ( xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("related") ) ? xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("related") : false; }
    catch(err) { err = true; relatedNode = false; }
    result += ( !relatedNode ) ? "<li>Scanner unable to retrieve relatedNode || "+err+"</li>" : "<li>Link scan found: "+relatedNode.length+" entries.</li>";
    if( relatedNode.length > 0 ) 
    {
        clearCache("relatedSelect");
        var selObj = document.getElementById("relatedSelect");
        for(var i = 0; i < relatedNode.length; i++)
        {
            val = unescape(relatedNode[i].getAttribute("url"));
            str = unescape(relatedNode[i].getAttribute("txt"));
            opt = document.createElement("option");
                opt.value = val;
                opt.innerHTML= ( str.length > 50 ) ? str.substring(0,48)+"..." : str;
            selObj.appendChild(opt);
        }
    }
</code>
```

All the above is working fine.  But everything goes south at submit time when the urls, (the   value), are external relative to greenfloyd.org.  Then, I get the "Go away and don't come back message..."  On the other hand, if the urls point to greenfloyd there's no problem and the bookmark is published, with links.  It's almost like I were trying to call the local script from some other domain.  The uls are not in any linkable context, they are treated as plain text in the value attribute of the option.  Although I do combine the url with the text using a seperator (*,*) between them so that php can unpack the value to produce seperate url and text fields that are stored on msqli... it's hacky, but it works, or at least it use to and I've yet to find a better alternative.   One other odd thing: when I gather the links in greenfloyd.org there are a couple external links and they are accepted!?

```
<code>
function bmSub()
{
...
    var selObj = document.getElementById("relatedSelect");
    var url, txt, val, sendCt=0;
    for ( var i = 0; i < selObj.options.length; i++  )
    {
        if ( selObj.options[i].selected )
        {
            url = selObj.options[i].value.trim();
            txt = selObj.options[i].innerHTML;
            val = url+"*,*"+txt;                // pack url and txt into the value attribute, php unpacks it into 2 db fields
            selObj.options[i].value = val;
            sendCt +=1;
        }
    } 
    resultDisplay("Link count: "+sendCt);

    var formElement = document.getElementById("bmInputForm");
    var formData = new FormData(formElement);
    var urlX = encodeURI("http://greenfloyd.org/greenfloyd/php/bm_input_xml.php?sid="+Math.random());
    xmlObj = GetXmlHttpObject();
    xmlObj.open("POST", urlX, false);
    xmlObj.send(formData);
// pause echo "<return err='$err' msg='$msg'></return>";
        try 
        {
            xmlDoc = xmlObj.responseXML;
            var returnNode = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("return"); 
            err = ( returnNode[0].getAttribute("err") == "1" ) ? true : false;
            msg = unescape(returnNode[0].getAttribute("msg"));
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            msg = "bmSub status : "+e+"<br>xml: "+xmlObj.statusText+", "+xmlObj.status+", size: "+xmlObj.responseText.length;
            err = true;
        }
        resultDisplay(msg);
        if ( err ) return;
</code>
```

Comment: Here's a related post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27998525/intermittent-http-403-forbidden-error-calling-same-ajax-code?rq=1, almost exactly like mine although I think I've isolated the problem with a little more  detail.

Comment: Per above ref, I just turned "modSecurity" (mod_security) off at the CP and that appears to have solved the problem.